# Can we customize the Site Content page layout?

Tags: page-layout

Compare the SP2010's view all site content, the SP2013 site content is not very user friendly. I want to customize the Site Content page view so that:

1. Classify different type of "APP" by categories
2. Modify the size of APP icon
3. Change the sorting

Is it possible? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the on-premise version, then yes you can modify it.
It's an Application page located in the `_layouts` folder, so it is accessible. It has some inline C# code which handles grouping etc. which you can modify.

Take a backup of it before you start tinkering with it.

Comment: It is too risky to touch it. Maybe I should just mock up it with CSS.